# CSS positioning: Full-width header shall have the same left margin as the centered content-div

Tags: css, web-applications, html, positioning

I am stuck and hope someone has an easy solution I've not thought about :-)

1. I have a 1040px centered div for page content, menu and footer.
2. The header image shall have the same left margin as the content div AND grow to the right side (for those with higher screen resolutions)

Is there any way to do this using CSS? I know, I could calculate the left margin of the content box with javascript and set the header-margin dynamically, but I would prefer a css solution.

Regards,
Martin

Comment: `margin-left: fixedWidth` and `width: inPercentage`. Is this what you want?

Answer (score 0):

Why not just place the header outside of the sitecontainer?

And then giving it a width of 100%, and a min-width of 1040px.
(Or stretch the background image, depending on if it's 1 color, or an image.)

Is that what you meant? Maybe post the HTML and the CSS, by the way.

Comment: I have the header outside the site container, but the issue is that the sitecontainer is centered. I have to find a way to enforce that the header has the same left margin as the sitecontainer. But I don't know how :-( No css available this time.. all just boxmodels.

Comment: <div id="growing-header" style="background-color: #00aaff;">
  Header
</div>
<div class="container_16" id="main"></div> <!-- has 1040px -->

Answer (score 0):

Alright, so what you mean is that the header does stretch across, but that the **content inside** the header (*a menu, a logo, whatever*) doesn't get centered like the sitecontainer.

If that's the case, here's what to do;

```
<div id="header">
  <div id="headercontent">
    <img src="logo.png">

    <nav>
      <ul>
      <li>menuitem</li>
      <li>menuitem</li>
      <li>menuitem</li>
      <li>menuitem</li>
      </ul>
    </nav>

  </div>
</div>
```

And for the **style** something like;

```
#footer{
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 1040px;
  color: [your header color];
}

#headercontent{
[in here you simply put the same styling as the sitecontainer]
}
```

Is that what you meant? I hope it helped.

Comment: I think I am constantly explaining wrong :-( Let me try it this way: I  want to achieve that the main area stays 1040px and centered while the header grows to the right --> http://www.cosketch.com/Rooms/kmjgikx